# Cheap CCTV/IP Camera to work with raspberry pi MotionEyeOS Or own its own software

Tags: video-camera, home-security, ip-camera

My subdivision is tired of speeders on our street. I would like to setup a camera outside of my house to catch some of the repeat offenders, every house on the street has small children, and its a very unsafe situation. This is something I'm doing on my own and without pay.

I need a single camera, or maybe two cameras depending on the PTZ features, I would like for them to run on MotionEyeOS on raspberry pi, but doesn't have to. If a camera is ethernet or wifi enabled, and has all the software to be setup already installed on it, thats fine.

---

Requirements

---

1. Clear picture at 100m or 300ish feet.
2. No additional hardware required, except a router and maybe a raspberry pi.
3. Outdoor rated
4. SOME Optical Zoom, have to be able to grab license plates after all.

---

Flexible requirements

---

1. Pan Tilt Zoom
2. Able to record speed by any means.
3. As cheap as possible, lets use <100$ as a starting point.
4. Cloud uploads (Dropbox, amazon cloud) features would REALLY be nice.

I was initially planing on using my raspberry pi 3, running motioneyeOS so I could live stream the video... However, if a camera is IP via Ethernet or wifi, and doesn't require another device hooked into it, that works for me. What I want to avoid is having the camera connected to a computer (other than the pi) or a traditional DVR.

Comment: Uhm, wouldn't this be better of in the [RaspberryPi stack](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @NZKshatriya not necessarily, If I have questions about wiring or setting up the motioneyeos then maybe. I don't know, maybe I'll edit the question to remove the raspberry pi requirement. It seems like me and you are the only ones on this site these days, what do you think?

Comment: seems so actually.  Wiring though....I wouldn't suppose there would be a stack dedicated to correct/efficient electrical wiring, and the standards and codes that apply would there? There seems to be a stack for everything else.  ArtOfCode is always here though, in the shadows.

Comment: My recommendation for capturing license plates would be to install the [CHDK firmware](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) on a Canon point-and-shoot.  The firmware provides motion trigger support and scripting abilities, and clever programming could probably get it to do what you want (eg. two shots: a high-shutter-speed one to grab the license plate, followed by a fixed-speed one to get vehicle speed by measuring motion blur).